# ListSubscriber and Error 500

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm attempting to build a subscription center and I'd like to query the ListSubscriber object to see the status of the subscriber so that I can update the form options that they see. Problem is, my code is causing an Internal Server Error (500)

I can't figure out what's wrong with my code.

```
VAR @listID, @subKey

SET @listID = listid
SET @subKey = subscriberid

Set @retrieveReq= CreateObject("RetrieveRequest")
    SetObjectProperty(@retrieveReq,"ObjectType","ListSubscriber")
    AddObjectArrayItem(@retrieveReq,"Properties","SubscriberKey")
    AddObjectArrayItem(@retrieveReq,"Properties","ListID")
    AddObjectArrayItem(@retrieveReq,"Properties","Status")

Set @sf1 = CreateObject("SimpleFilterPart")
    SetObjectProperty(@sf1,"Property","ListID")
    SetObjectProperty(@sf1,"SimpleOperator","equals")
    AddObjectArrayItem(@sf1,"Value",@listID)

Set @sf2 = CreateObject("SimpleFilterPart")
    SetObjectProperty(@sf2,"Property","SubscriberKey")
    SetObjectProperty(@sf2,"SimpleOperator","equals")
    AddObjectArrayItem(@sf2,"Value",@subKey)

Set @cf1 = CreateObject("ComplexFilterPart")
    SetObjectProperty(@cf1,"LeftOperand",@sf1)
    SetObjectProperty(@cf1,"RightOperand",@sf2)
    SetObjectProperty(@cf1,"LogicalOperator","AND")

SetObjectProperty(@retrieveReq,"Filter",@cf1)

SET @srow = InvokeRetrieve(@retrieveReq)

SET @subStatus = Field(@srow, "Status")
```

Comment: If you comment out your `InvokeRetrieve()` what do you get?  Do `listid` and `subscriberid` have values?

Comment: @AdamSpriggs I removed the `InvokeRetrieve()` and printed `@listID` and `@subKey` to the page - both values were there. The lead is getting to the page through an email where the link is generated using `%%=CloudPagesURL()=%%`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use the `row()` function before `field()`.

```
%%[

VAR @listID, @subKey

SET @listID = AttributeValue("listid")
SET @subKey = AttributeValue("subscriberid")

Set @retrieveReq= CreateObject("RetrieveRequest")
SetObjectProperty(@retrieveReq,"ObjectType","ListSubscriber")
AddObjectArrayItem(@retrieveReq,"Properties","SubscriberKey")
AddObjectArrayItem(@retrieveReq,"Properties","ListID")
AddObjectArrayItem(@retrieveReq,"Properties","Status")

Set @sf1 = CreateObject("SimpleFilterPart")
SetObjectProperty(@sf1,"Property","ListID")
SetObjectProperty(@sf1,"SimpleOperator","equals")
AddObjectArrayItem(@sf1,"Value",@listID)

Set @sf2 = CreateObject("SimpleFilterPart")
SetObjectProperty(@sf2,"Property","SubscriberKey")
SetObjectProperty(@sf2,"SimpleOperator","equals")
AddObjectArrayItem(@sf2,"Value",@subKey)

Set @cf1 = CreateObject("ComplexFilterPart")
SetObjectProperty(@cf1,"LeftOperand",@sf1)
SetObjectProperty(@cf1,"RightOperand",@sf2)
SetObjectProperty(@cf1,"LogicalOperator","AND")

SetObjectProperty(@retrieveReq,"Filter",@cf1)

var @requestID, @RequestStatus
set @srow = InvokeRetrieve(@retrieveReq, @RequestStatus,@RequestID);

if RowCount(@srow) > 0 then
    set @subStatus = field(Row(@srow,1),"Status")
endif

]%%
```

Comment: Seems to be the case. No longer experiencing a crippling 500 error. The `subStatus` isn't returning a value - but that'll take some more exploration. Thanks!